# Using structures for singly linked lists

Tags: c, singly-linked-list

I've been wondering:

```
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
}*head;
```

I believe the *head variable is the first pointer of linked list, but why is it written outside of structure brackets? Why I need to write it outside of whole structure? Could anyone answer, because I'm abit lost in whole linked list thing. And why do we need to declare *next pointer with "struct node" if it is already in whole "node" structure?

Comment: You define a struct and a variable head. That is the syntax.

Comment: could I just write a new line `int *head;` instead?

Comment: Sure, you can do: `struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
} ; struct node* head;` Which is matching your code.

Comment: `*head` after the struct means declaring a `struct node *` with identifier `head`. It's the same as saying `struct node *head;`.

Comment: Alright, got it. And what about `struct node *next;`? Why do I need to declare `*next` with a `struct node` if the pointer is already in the structure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`head` is just a pointer of type `struct node*`. An equivalent declaration is:

```
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};
struct node *head;
```

Note that even if you don't declare any variable of the type of the structure you're defining, you must put a semicolon after the closing curly brace.

The origin of this syntax is that the struct is a data type and the way you declare variables is by specifying their data type and their name. Indeed, you can do this:

```
struct {int a, b;} *variable;
```